# Как изменить размер фотографии в px?

Tags: java, android

Есть Bitmap (фотография) надо сделать его 250px на 250 px. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Простое решение с подобного вопроса на [enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/244177/10719456):

```
BufferedImage createResizedCopy(Image originalImage, 
            int scaledWidth, int scaledHeight, 
            boolean preserveAlpha)
    {
        System.out.println("resizing...");
        int imageType = preserveAlpha ? BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB : BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB;
        BufferedImage scaledBI = new BufferedImage(scaledWidth, scaledHeight, imageType);
        Graphics2D g = scaledBI.createGraphics();
        if (preserveAlpha) {
            g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src);
        }
        g.drawImage(originalImage, 0, 0, scaledWidth, scaledHeight, null); 
        g.dispose();
        return scaledBI;
    }
```

**Запускать после загрузки изображения.**